# to find the total no of letter in a string. please checkout my code too

Tags: c

I am trying to write this code the build is successful but the output is coming with just one character.

I am writing this code in the x-code. I got this code from a course. which was completely working on his codeblock. I tried it to do on codeblock but it wasn't working on the codeblock too. help me if it is wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int compute(char c, char str[])
{
    int r=0;
    long len=strlen(str);
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
        if (str[i]==c)
        {
            r++;
        }
    }

    return r;
}

int main()
{
    char text[]="C language is a very powerful language that allows programmers to fully control their computers";
    int i;
    long len=strlen(text);

    for (i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
        char c=text[i];
        c= tolower(c);
        text[i]=c;
    }

    bool seen[256];

    for (i=0; i<256; i++)
    {
        seen[i]=false;
    }

    for (i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
        char c= text[i];

        if (seen[c]==true)
            continue;

        seen[c]=true;

        int ocs=compute(c, text);

        if (ocs>0)
        {
            printf("%c  :  %d  -:",c,ocs);
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

I expect the out to be this-:
' ' : 14 | 'a' : 8 | 'c' : 3 | 'e' : 7 | 'f' : 2 | 'g' : 5 | 'h' : 2 | 'i' : 2 | 'l' : 8 | 'm' : 3 | 'n' : 3 | 'o' : 7 | 'p' : 3 | 'r' : 8 | 's' : 4 | 't' : 6 | 'u' : 5 | 'v' : 1 | 'w' : 2 | 'y' : 2 |
but the output is just this-:
'c' : 3

Answer (score 2):

Take your `return 0;` outside the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

regarding:

```
long len=strlen(text);
```

The function: `strlen()` returns a 'size_t' (effectively a 'unsigned long int') the posted code is assigning that to a 'long int'  This is risky.  Suggest using:

```
size_t len = strlen( text );
```

BTW: notice the appropriate use of horizontal spacing for readability by humans

regarding:

```
long len=strlen(text);

for (i=0; i<len; i++)
{
    char c=text[i];
    c= tolower(c);
    text[i]=c;
}
```

this mess can be replaced by:

```
for( size_t i=0; text[i]; i++ )
{
    text[i] = tolower( text[i] );
}
```

which stops the loop when the trailing NUL byte is encountered

regarding:

```
bool seen[256];

for (i=0; i<256; i++)
{
    seen[i]=false;
}
```

this can be replaced with the simple

```
int seen[ 256 ] = {0};
```

Remember that any value other than 0 is seen as 'true'

The following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality
3. contains an appropriate comment for each code block
4. uses the NUL byte at the end of the text to terminate some loops
5. avoids 'magic' numbers (like 256)
6. does not include header files that are not used
7. corrects the logic error of a 'return' inside the final loop

And now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>  // printf()
#include <ctype.h>  // tolower()

#define MAX_CHAR 256

int main( void )
{
    char text[]="C language is a very powerful language that allows programmers to fully control their computers";

    // set all text to lower case
    for ( int i=0; text[i]; i++ )
    {
        text[i] = (char)tolower( text[i] );
    }

    // init work array to all 0's
    int seen[ MAX_CHAR ] = {0};

    // count how many times each char in text
    for (size_t i=0; text[i]; i++)
    {
        seen[ (int)text[i] ]++;
    }

    // loop through array, displaying each char in text 
    // and how many times it was seen
    for( int i=0; i<MAX_CHAR; i++ ) 
    {
        if( seen[i] )
        {
            printf( "%c  :  %d -:", i, seen[i] );
        }
    }
}
```

when run, this is the resulting output:

```
   :  14 -:a  :  8 -:c  :  3 -:e  :  7 -:f  :  2 -:g  :  5 -:h  :  2 -:i  :  2 -:l  :  8 -:m  :  3 -:n  :  3 -:o  :  7 -:p  :  3 -:r  :  8 -:s  :  4 -:t  :  6 -:u  :  5 -:v  :  1 -:w  :  2 -:y  :  2 -:
```

suggest reformatting the output for readability